# Package with React 17 use in react 16

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to use a package that is build with React 17.0.2 to use in React 16.3.1?

Our Project is quite old (React version 16.3.1) and we like to use the [react-battery-gauge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-battery-gauge?activeTab=dependencies) in our project. Is that possible or is the only way to upgrade our project?

Comment: Why don't you upgrade your React version? It has minor breaking changes that will likely not effect you https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html And even going to React 18 is not a big change

Answer (score 1):

Using a package built for React 17.0.2 in a React 16.3.1 project is generally not recommended and can lead to compatibility issues. React versions often introduce changes, and packages may rely on features or APIs that are not available in earlier versions.